# Не запускается .exe, но ошибок нет (Process finished with exit code 0), Python 3

Tags: python, exe, ос, subprocess

Код (Python 3, PyCharm):
import os
os.startfile("C:/Users/injen/Desktop/PyProjects/Hausaufgabe2/simulation/simulation.exe")

Программа не совершает никаких действий, просто завершается без ошибок.
Данный .exe был создан экспортом из Processing 3.4.5.

Вариант с r"C:/Users/injen/Desktop/PyProjects/Hausaufgabe2/simulation/simulation.exe" ничего не меняет. Причём файлы с любым другим расширением открывает, а также открывает другие .exe, которые не были созданы мной (на данном ПК), но не открывает никакие .exe созданные в Processing 3.4.5 (руками - мышкой - .exe-шники Processing запускаются и работают).

Команда
subprocess.call('C:/Users/injen/Desktop/PyProjects/Hausaufgabe2/simulation/simulation.exe')
тоже не работает (ничего не делает без ошибок).

Путь в Path до папки с этим exe прописан.

В чём может быть дело? Или как по-другому запустить .exe?

Comment: P.S. версия Processing 3.5.4 - в вопросе опечатка

Comment: `os.system(f'path to exe')`

Comment: @ganz os.system(f'path to exe') даёт такой же результат

Comment: из консоли экзешники запускаются?

Comment: @ganz запускаются

Comment: не работает даже `print`? `print(os.system(f'..'))` что возвращает? мб поможет `os.chdir(f'path to exe folder')`

Comment: @ganz print возвращает 0; os.chdir выдаёт ошибку <NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] Неверно задано имя папки: ' . . '  (но указано всё верно)

Comment: если действительно задано '..' то действительно не верно, требуется с одной точкой. Предлагаю исспользовать абсолютные пути